# How to redirect browser page output to another browser running on a different machine

Tags: browser

I would like to know whether it is feasible to redirect a HTML page (say output of - http://acid3.acidtests.org/ ) from one browser (say A) to another browser (say B) running on a different machine? 
Thanks and Regards,
Souvik

Comment: Redirect or display? For Firefox, it is possible to render a page with IE's engine with the help of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In short no.

A slightly longer version, to allow the answer to be long enough to count as an answer would be that it would be a security risk if you could.